# Not going to release apk after expo eject

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

I created a new project at **Expo**, after which I was already building it using `expo build`but over time I needed to move away from **Expo** a little and execute an `expo eject`, and then continue development on regular **React Native**.

I ran into the following situation: I am trying to build an **apk** file with the `./gradlew assembleRelease` command, but I get a **debug** build instead of **release**, I don’t understand why this is happening, I tried to follow the build instructions specifically for the release version - unsuccessfully.

I also tried to create a new project without using **Expo** - the whole scenario described above worked correctly and I got a **release** build of my application, and with all that, I compared the `android/app/build.gradle` files in these two projects and they are almost identical in terms of their configuration.

My main task and problem is to build the **release** version of the **apk** file and understand why, with different attempts to build, I only get the **debug apk**.